# Format a message using MessageFormat.format() in Java

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I have stored some messages in a resource bundle. I'm trying to format these messages as follows.

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;

String text = MessageFormat.format("You're about to delete {0} rows.", 5);
System.out.println(text);
```

Assume that the first parameter i.e the actual message is stored in a property file which is somehow retrieved.

The second parameter i.e 5 is a dynamic value and should be placed in the placeholder `{0}` which doesn't happen. The next line prints,

> Youre about to delete {0} rows.

The placeholder is not replaced with the actual parameter.

---

It is the apostrophe here - `You're`. I have tried to escape it as usual like `You\\'re` though it didn't work. What changes are needed to make it work?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Add an extra apostrophe `'` to the `MessageFormat` pattern `String` to ensure the `'` character is displayed

```
String text = 
     java.text.MessageFormat.format("You''re about to delete {0} rows.", 5);
                                         ^
```

An apostrophe (aka *single quote*) in a MessageFormat pattern starts a quoted string and is not interpreted on its own. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

> A single quote itself must be represented by doubled single quotes '' throughout a String.

The `String` `You\\'re` is equivalent to adding a backslash character to the `String` so the only difference will be that `You\re` will be produced rather than `Youre`. (before double quote solution `''` applied)

Comment: Is there any other method to do format like this but not converting single quote to double single quote?  because it is annoying.

Comment: Why in C # I do not need to do this?

Answer (score 14):

Just be sure you have used double apostrophe  ('')

```
String text = java.text.MessageFormat.format("You''re about to delete {0} rows.", 5);
System.out.println(text);
```

**Edit:**

> Within a String, a pair of single quotes can be used to quote any arbitrary characters except single quotes. For example, pattern string "'{0}'" represents string "{0}", not a FormatElement.
>   ...
>
> Any unmatched quote is treated as closed at the end of the given pattern. For example, pattern string "**'**{0}" is treated as pattern "**'**{0}**'**".

Source http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Answer (score 6):

You need to use double apostrophe instead of single in the "You''re", eg:

```
String text = java.text.MessageFormat.format("You''re about to delete {0} rows.", 5);
System.out.println(text);
```

Answer (score 5):

Using an apostrophe `’` (Unicode: `\u2019`) instead of a single quote `'` fixed the issue without doubling the `\'`.

Answer (score 3):

For everyone that has Android problems in the string.xml, use \'\' instead of single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that does not require editing the code and works regardless of the number of characters.

```
String text = 
  java.text.MessageFormat.format(
    "You're about to delete {0} rows.".replaceAll("'", "''"), 5);
```

Comment: Why replaceAll if it's not a regex? Can only use replace