# Troubling with printing with MessageFormat in java

Tags: java

The program is working just fine, but when the last line is printed it'd go like this: 
[image]

I tried doing it like this,because it's a symbol :

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("The rectangle\'s area is {0}", area));
```

But it's still the same result. It'll only work , if I remove the symbol ->" ' ".

And I don't want suggestions of how I should write my the code. Only asking where is my mistake. Thank you

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*4. Rectangles

        Write an expression that calculates rectangle’s perimeter and area by given width and height.*/
public class Rectangles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter width:");
        double width = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter height:");
        double height = scan.nextDouble();
        double area = 2 * width + 2* height;
        double perimeter = width*height;
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Perimeter {0}",perimeter));
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("The rectangle's area is {0}", area));

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569608/format-a-message-using-messageformat-format-in-java/17569639

Comment: Hm, I couldn't find that when I searched. My bad. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever you are using MessageFormat you should be aware that the
>   single quote character (') fulfils a special purpose inside message
>   patterns. The single quote is used to represent a section within the
>   message pattern that will not be formatted. A single quote itself must
>   be escaped by using two single quotes ('').

[Messageformat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("The rectangle'' area is {0}", area));
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

{} part of the format function denotes the index of the arguments passed, in this case width and height.width is stored at args[0] while height stored at args[1] for the above program.So {0} should be the format element for width while {1} should be the formatelement for height unlike the above program where {0} is chosen as formatelement for height as well.Moreover Area is being printed in the last line , May be the scope of the args[] parameter ended one line before. I tried printing both area and perimeter using the same line using {1} and {0} respectively and it worked well.