# is it safe to use java.text.MessageFormat.format() when creating an sql query?

Tags: java, database, mssql-jdbc

I am using **MessageFormat.format()** to create the String for my PreparedStatement. I read that using **StringBuilder** may be a cause of sql injection. Is it the same for MessageFormat?

the code goes like this

```
String SQL
        = "select CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, CT.{0} as ID, t.*\n"
        + "from changetable (changes {1}, ?) as CT \n"
        + "left outer join {2} as t \n"
        + "on t.{3} = CT.{4} \n"
        + "order by CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION";

String finalSQL = MessageFormat.format(SQL, primaryKey, table, table, primaryKey, primaryKey);
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(finalSQL);
```

Comment: Use a library to escape all user input

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569608/format-a-message-using-messageformat-format-in-java

Comment: @toastedDeli There is no user input. I am using it in a switch case instead of writing the same script 50 times.

Comment: If `primaryKey` and `table` do not include user input, it should be safe. However using a `StringBuilder` would be safe as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an SQL string as you do with filling in *table and column names* would only be unsafe (SQL injection) when the variable strings stem from some passed input.

Hence `StringBuilder` might even be more sound (clear) than a `MessageFormat`. On the other way a format is more readable.

As named placeholders would be even nicer, consider Apache Common `StringSubstitutor` or such.

In every case code checkers might warn for SQL injection on this.

Sometimes you can use

```
DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
```

and use table and column names for operation on the meta data.

This is a largely DB vendor independent way of JDBC to query the database.

Answer (score 1):

This is not safe. `MessageFormat.format` just replaces the occurrences of {x} in the given string with the given objects without escaping the latter.
Therefore it is equivalent to string concatenation.

To build an SQL query that includes data from variables one should always use prepared statements.