# Store formatted strings, pass in values later?

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates, string-formatting, f-string

I have a dictionary with a lot of strings.

Is it possible to store a formatted string with *placeholders* and pass in a actual values later?

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
d = {
  "message": f"Hi There, {0}"
}

print(d["message"].format("Dave"))
```

The above code obviously doesn't work but I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: You could make a lambda function to be called later

Comment: what do you mean it does not work, it print's properly for me. I see you edited it for `f-strings` now, but your prior attempt worked fine fwiw

Comment: Uh, your code was working perfectly fine when "message" was not an f-string. That is still a valid formatting method in Python3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You use f-string; it already interpolated `0` in there. You might want to remove `f` there

```
d = {
          # no f here
  "message": "Hi There, {0}"
}

print(d["message"].format("Dave"))
```

```
Hi There, Dave
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Issue: mixing f-String with str.format

| Technique | Python version |
| --- | --- |
| [*f-String*](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) | since 3.6 |
| [`str.format`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#option-2-strformat) | since 2.6 |

Your dict-value contains an *f-String* which is **immediately evaluated**.
So the expression inside the curly-braces (was `{0}`) is directly interpolated (became `0`), hence the value assigned became `"Hi There, 0"`.

When applying the `.format` argument `"Dave"`, this was neglected because string already lost the templating `{}` inside. Finally string was printed as is:

> Hi There, 0

#### Attempt to use f-String

What happens if we use a variable name like `name` instead of the constant integer `0` ?

Let's try on Python's console (REPL):

```
>>> d = {"message": f"Hi There, {name}"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

OK, we must define the variable before. Let's assume we did:

```
>>> name = "Dave"; d = {"message": f"Hi There, {name}"}
>>> print(d["message"])
Hi There, Dave
```

This works. But it requires the variable or expression inside the curly-braces to be valid at runtime, at location of definition: `name` is required to be defined before.

#### Breaking a lance for `str.format`

There are reasons

- when you need to read *templates* from **external sources** (e.g. file or database)
- when not variables but *placeholders* are configured **independently from your source**

Then indexed-placeholders should be preferred to named-variables.

Consider a given database column *message* with  value `"Hello, {1}. You are {0}."`. It can be read and used independently from the implementation (programming-language, surrounding code).

For example

- in Java: `MessageFormat.format(message, 74, "Eric")`
- in Python: `message.format(74, 'Eric')`.

See also:
[Format a message using MessageFormat.format() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569608/format-a-message-using-messageformat-format-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably late to the party but this is another way to solve it using named variables.
At least, when I came along looking for the same type of solution, it's what I came up with.

```
d = "Hello {name}"
g = { 'name': 'world' }
d.format(**g)
```