# Kotlin String substitution not working when string is read from file

Tags: kotlin

I have written a code that reads a text file. The text files contain placeholders which I would like to replace. The substitution does not work this way and the string is printed with the placeholders. Here is the code that I have written for this:

```
class TestSub(val sub: Sub) {

    fun create() = template()

    fun template() = Files.newBufferedReader(ClassPathResource(templateId.location).file.toPath()).readText()
}

data class Sub(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

Here is the main function that tries to print the final string:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val sub = Sub("Prashant", 32)

    println(TestSub(sub).create())
}
```

However, when, instead of reading a file, I use a String, the following code works (Replacing `fun template()`)

```
fun template() = "<h1>Hello ${sub.name}. Your age is ${sub.age}</h1>"
```

Is there a way to make string Substitution work when reading the content of a file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Kotlin does not support String templates from files. I.e. **code** like `"some variable: $variable"` gets compiled to `"some variable: " + variable`. String templates are handled at compile time, which means it does not work with text loaded from files, or if you do something else to get the String escaped into a raw form. Either way, it would, as [danielspaniol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52179138/6296561) mentioned, be a security threat.

That leaves three options:

- `String.format(str)`
- `MessageFormat.format(str)`
- Creating a custom engine

I don't know what your file contains, but if it's the String you used in the template function, change it to:

```
<h1>Hello {0}. Your age is {1,integer}</h1>
```

This is for `MessageFormat`, which is my personal preference. If you use `String.format`, use `%s` instead, and the other appropriate formats.

Now, use that in `MessageFormat.format`:

```
val result = MessageFormat.format(theString, name, age);
```

Note that if you use `MessageFormat`, you'll need to escape `'` as `''`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189889/6296561).

Answer (score 2):

String substitution using `${...}` is part of the string literals syntax and works roughly like this

```
val a = 1
val b = "abc ${a} def"  // gets translated to something like val b = "abc " + a + " def"
```

So there is no way for this to work when you load from a text file. This would also be a huge security risk as it would allow for arbitrary code execution.

However I assume that Kotlin has something like a `sprintf` function where you can have placeholders like `%s` in your string and you can replace them with values

---

Take a look [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/java-string-format-alternative-in-kotlin/703). It looks like the easiest way is to use `String.format`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something **similar to Kotlin String templates** for raw Strings, where placeholders like **$var** or **${var}** are substituted by values, but this functionality needs to be available at runtime (for text read from files).

Methods like `String.format(str)` or `MessageFormat.format(str)` use other formats than the notation with the dollar prefix of Kotlin String templates. For "Kotlin-like" placeholder substitution you could use the function below (which I developed for similar reasons). It supports placeholders as $var or ${var} as well as dollar escaping by ${'$'}

```
/**
 * Returns a String in which placeholders (e.g. $var or ${var}) are replaced by the specified values.
 * This function can be used for resolving templates at RUNTIME (e.g. for templates read from files).
 *
 * Example: 
  * "\$var1\${var2}".resolve(mapOf("var1" to "VAL1", "var2" to "VAL2")) 
  * returns VAL1VAL2
 */
fun String.resolve(values: Map<String, String>): String {

    val result = StringBuilder()

    val matcherSimple = "\\$([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)"           // simple placeholder e.g. $var
    val matcherWithBraces = "\\$\\{([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)}"   // placeholder within braces e.g. ${var}

    // match a placeholder (like $var or ${var}) or ${'$'} (escaped dollar)
    val allMatches = Regex("$matcherSimple|$matcherWithBraces|\\\$\\{'(\\\$)'}").findAll(this)

    var position = 0
    allMatches.forEach {
        val range = it.range
        val placeholder = this.substring(range)
        val variableName = it.groups.filterNotNull()[1].value
        val newText =
            if ("\${'\$'}" == placeholder) "$"
            else values[variableName] ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Could not resolve placeholder $placeholder")
        result.append(this.substring(position, range.start)).append(newText)
        position = range.last + 1
    }
    result.append(this.substring(position))
    return result.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String templates only work for compile-time Sting literals, while what u read from a file is generated at runtime.

What u need is a template engine, which can render templates with variables or models at runtime.

For simple cases, `String.format` or `MessageFormat.format` in Java would work.

And for complex cases, check thymeleaf, velocity and so on.