# String format - java

Tags: java, messageformat

What is the best way to replace 'gift' and 'price' from below string using java-

We’ve added {gift} coupon worth {price}. Enjoy!

Also can i use MessageFormat in any way to solve above problem.

Comment: `replace("{gift}", "Ferrari").replace("{price}", "1$")`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/189955/10005752

Answer (score 2):

Something like the below works:

```
String str = "We’ve added {gift} coupon worth {price}. Enjoy!";

System.out.println(str);

str = str.replace("{gift}", "unicorns");
str = str.replace("{price}", "$399");

System.out.println(str);
```

You can't use a MessageFormat to replace text in the input `String` you've provided, but if you save your `String` as a format to use it MessageFormat, it makes it a lot easier to read:

```
String defaultFormat = "We’ve added {0} coupon worth {1}. Enjoy!";

String defaultOutput = MessageFormat.format(defaultFormat, "unicorns", "$399");
System.out.println(defaultOutput);
defaultOutput = MessageFormat.format(defaultFormat, "leprechaun", "$199");
System.out.println(defaultOutput);

String yodaOutput = MessageFormat.format("coupon worth {1} we have added for {0}. Enjoy!", "unicorns", "$399");
System.out.println(yodaOutput);
```