# Needs to print data in JSON format using wicket and javascript

Tags: javascript, wicket

The following code I have implemented in the wicket. It is printing the entire JSON data in a single line. Actually it should print in a JSON format. As of my understanding, the problem is with  `document.getElementById(''demo'').innerHTML={0}`. Please correct my code if I did anything wrong.

And why `(''demo'')` is expecting two single quotes at starting and ending of Html id.

```
target.appendJavaScript(MessageFormat
                    .format("document.getElementById(''demo'').innerHTML={0}'", mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                                    .writeValueAsString(jsonDataProducer())));
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but JSON data is always in JSON format.

Comment: yes, it is in JSON format only. I'm asking for pretty print format. Not like entire JSON data printing in a single line.

Comment: I don't understand why you use two single quotes with getElementById. And 'demo' should correspond to a <pre> tag if you want to display the prettified  JSON

Comment: @Andrea Del Bene sorry for the delay.  In MessageFormat  "A single quote itself must be represented by doubled single quotes ''. I got this from following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189889/java-messageformat-how-can-i-insert-values-between-single-quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer to my question.

```
target.appendJavaScript(MessageFormat
                        .format("document.getElementById(''demo'').innerHTML=JSON.stringify({0},null,2);", jsonDataProducer));
```

First I tried to print the pretty JSON with the following code. `mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonDataProducer().toString())`
But, javascript is taking it as a object When I assign it to the `document.getElementById(''demo'').innerHTML`.
So, I used `JSON.stringify({0},null,2)`. It will stringify the javascript object in prettified JSON format.

And in `MessageFormat` a pair of single quotes are treated as a single quote.
From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189889/java-messageformat-how-can-i-insert-values-between-single-quotes) I got MessageFormat single quote information. We can also read MessageFormat documentation.