# Java MessageFormat fails to format specific string

Tags: java, string-formatting, messageformat

I have a constant declared as following:

```
protected static final String LOC_RC_ELT = "[id*='rcLine'][id$='paxIndex{0}']";
```

And then I use MessageFormat:

```
MessageFormat.format(LOC_RC_ELT, paxIndex)
```

In this case MessageFormat fails to format the string declared as constant:

[image]

This is not true for other cases like:

```
LOC_RC_SELECTED_TAB = "[id*=_rc-tabs{0}] .tabSelected"
```

This works just fine:

[image]

Why I'm getting this weird behavior ? and how can I solve it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think it has something to do with the single quotes. What happens when `LOC_RC_ELT` is `"[id*='rcLine'][id$=paxIndex{0}]";`? Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/189955/5675692

Answer (score 2):

Weird behavior, but as specified.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

> Within a *String*, a pair of single quotes can be used to quote any arbitrary characters except single quotes. For example, pattern string `"'{0}'"` represents string `"{0}"`, not a *FormatElement*. A single quote itself must be represented by doubled single quotes `''` throughout a *String*.