# Invalid Number Exception in SQL when trying to call select statement from Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to call a `select` query from my Java Program but i am getting `Invalid Number`error.
I am trying to call the query something like this

`code`

```
 String[] l_arr = new String[]{"CUSTOMERCUMULATIVELIMIT"};

    l_rs = JDBCEngine.executeQuery(MessageFormat.format(
                        " SELECT  LIMITS,  P.PACKAGE_ID  FROM MSTGLOBALLIMITSPACKAGE P  ,MSTCUSTOMERPROFILE C  WHERE P.PACKAGE_ID = {0}   AND C.ID_CUST = ?    AND C.ID_ENTITY = ?  AND C.TYPEUSER = ?  AND C.ID_ENTITY = P.ID_ENTITY  AND P.PACKAGE_ID NOT LIKE ?",l_arr );
```

I am getting query something like  this:

`Result`

```
SELECT LIMITS, P.PACKAGE_ID
  FROM MSTGLOBALLIMITSPACKAGE P, MSTCUSTOMERPROFILE C
 WHERE P.PACKAGE_ID = CUSTOMERCUMULATIVELIMIT
   AND C.ID_CUST = '00000144'
   AND C.ID_ENTITY = 'B001'
   AND C.TYPEUSER = 'ECU'
   AND C.ID_ENTITY = P.ID_ENTITY
   AND P.PACKAGE_ID NOT LIKE '*%'
```

I am getting the error Invalid number in the line `P.PACKAGE_ID = {0}`. I gone through and come to know that if i use `to_char` i can avoid this error. But I am not sure how to use `to_char` in `P.PACKAGE_ID = {0}`.

Also `PACKAGE_ID`  is of type `Varchar2` and `CUSTOMERCUMULATIVELIMIT` is a column in `MSTCUSTOMERPROFILE` of type `Number`.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is Package_ID a varchar or char type in your table schema? Similarly, how about other columns?

Comment: and why you put there {0} ?

Comment: Package_ID is of type ```varchar2```

Comment: @Massimo String.format()

Comment: why do you use String.format instead of a parameter ? And which value you pass in it in place of {0}?

Comment: @Saurav, can you share the exact error?
Not sure but you may want to consider this for the pattern matching at the end of your query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/189955/5199194

Comment: Now its clear why you use message.format, it's because you want to make a dynaic join, right ? Are you sure the error is in the P.PACKAGE_ID = CUSTOMERCUMULATIVELIMIT clause ? Oracle should translate the numbers into strings automatically during query execution. See this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53182/1. What are the data  types of the other join fields ? Can you hare your ddl (or at least the relevant part of it ) ?

Comment: Why are you comparing strings with numbers? At least one of those two columns has the wrong datatype.

Comment: Why are you choosing to use commas in the `FROM` clause rather than proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add to_char to your sql, change {0} to to_char({0})

`l_rs = JDBCEngine.executeQuery(MessageFormat.format( " SELECT LIMITS, P.PACKAGE_ID FROM MSTGLOBALLIMITSPACKAGE P ,MSTCUSTOMERPROFILE C WHERE P.PACKAGE_ID = to_char({0}) AND C.ID_CUST = ? AND C.ID_ENTITY = ? AND C.TYPEUSER = ? AND C.ID_ENTITY = P.ID_ENTITY AND P.PACKAGE_ID NOT LIKE ?",l_arr );`

Answer (score 0):

You are working with this line :

```
WHERE P.PACKAGE_ID = CUSTOMERCUMULATIVELIMIT
```

As there are no single quotes, SQL consider CUSTOMERCUMULATIVELIMIT as a number, not a string.

Adding quotes should solve this.

```
l_rs = JDBCEngine.executeQuery(MessageFormat.format(
                        " SELECT  LIMITS,  P.PACKAGE_ID  FROM MSTGLOBALLIMITSPACKAGE P  ,MSTCUSTOMERPROFILE C  WHERE P.PACKAGE_ID = '{0}'   AND C.ID_CUST = ?    AND C.ID_ENTITY = ?  AND C.TYPEUSER = ?  AND C.ID_ENTITY = P.ID_ENTITY  AND P.PACKAGE_ID NOT LIKE ?",l_arr );
```

Comment: CUSTOMERCUMULATIVELIMIT is a column of another table, not a string.

Comment: Right. But as said, PACKAGE_ID  is varchar2 and CUSTOMERCUMULATIVELIMIT is number. You can't match on different types. So, problem.